# Show that for each even n, there exists a graph with n vertices, such that the 2-approx VC alg returns a VC which is exactly twice the Minimum-VC

Tags: algorithms, graphs, approximation, vertex-cover

**Question:** Show that for each even n, there exists a graph with n vertices, such that the ALG(algorithm) returns a vertex cover which is **exactly** twice the size of minimum vertex cover.

**Define ALG:** simple 2-approximation deterministic algorithm for the vertex cover problem in an unweighted graph.
Output of ALG: vertex cover which is at most twice the size of minimum vertex cover.

**How will we show that?**

**My struggle:** I tried to solve this in the following way(below), **BUT** I'm not sure that my proof is correct, meaning that, **will there always exist a bipartite graph when n is even**?

**How I will approach the proof:** We’ll show that maximum matching in a graph is equal to the size of minimum vertex cover, and then we’ll show that the output of ALG is exactly twice the size of maximum matching, and thus is twice the size of minimum vertex cover. And thus, there always exists a bi-partite graph which is divided to two distinct sets of size n/2 which contains a minimum vertex cover that is exactly half the vertex cover.

**My proof:**

**Step 1:** There always exists a graph, which is bipartite, that maximum matching in it is equal to the size of minimum vertex cover, in that graph.
Proof: Kőnig's theorem states that, in any bipartite graph, the number of edges in a maximum matching is equal to the number of vertices in a minimum vertex cover.

**Step 2:** A matching in graph G is a set of edges such that no two edges share a common vertex. A maximal matching M is a matching such that we cannot add any of the remaining edge into M while maintaining the matching constraint, in other word, if we add any of the edge then M will not be a valid matching anymore. Note that maximal matching is different with maximum matching. Maximum matching deals with the largest possible matching set. So, maximum matching is a maximal matching, but the converse is not necessarily true (see figure below for clarity).
[image]

Figure 4 corresponds to a maximum matching (we cannot do better than 3), but both Figure 4 and Figure 5 are valid maximal matchings (we cannot add any of the remaining edge to the set while not violating the matching condition).

We can conclude that is it’s maximum matching is ALWAYS maximal matching. (vice versa not always true).

**Define C:** the output of **ALG** – which is the vertex cover set of the “2-approx for minimum vertex cover problem”.

Let’s add also the ALG  algorithm for more clarity:

```
1: C = Ø
2: while there is uncovered edge (u,v)
3:   add vertex u into C
4:   add vertex v into C
5: return C
```

That’s it! For all uncovered edges (in any order), we only need to add both endpoints into the cover set (line 3 and 4). 
In other words,

**Define:** If a graph has a minimum vertex set of size C*, then the algorithm will always provide a solution of cost C such that C <= 2C*.

**Proof:**

- Claim: The approximation ratio of the algorithm is 2.
- Let S* be a vertex cover of optimal size |S*| = C*.
- Let E# be the set of edges picked by the algorithm.
- Every edge in E# has at least one vertex in S*.
- Every edge in E# has 2 vertices in S.
- There are no other vertices in S.
- Thus, the size of S is at most twice the size of S*.
- C/C* <= 2

**Step 3:**

Lemma: The proposed algorithm ALG produce a maximal matching.
Every pair added into C in the algorithm is unique, it will not add edge (u,v) and (u,w) because when it encounters edge (u,v), it will add both vertex u and v, hence edge (u,w) will be covered by vertex u. Therefore, the algorithm will produce a matching in G, and it is maximal because it iterates until there is no uncovered edges.

**Define:** **M** – maximal matching.

**Step 4:**

From the algorithm and Lemma, we can conclude that the algorithm produce a vertex cover with size 2|**M**| (for each matching, we pick both vertices).
Thus,because of **step 4** and **step 1**, the algorithm produce a vertex cover with size 2 * number of vertices in a minimum vertex cover.
And because n is even, the graph that will exist is bipartite with distinct sets of size n/2.

Q.E.D

Comment: Yes, for every $n$ there exists a bipartite graph having $n$ vertices. Some examples include the empty graph, a cycle, any forest, and so on. For some of these graphs (for example, the empty graph) the maximum matching algorithm is optimal, so I don't think that your proof works (without reading it).

Comment: Can you focus your question? Nobody is going to read your proof attempt. Do you have a *specific* step you are not sure of, or perhaps a gap you are not sure how to fill?

Comment: Try a complete balanced bipartite graph.

Comment: I don't follow your definition of the algorithm.  All you say is "simple 2-approximation deterministic algorithm for the vertex cover problem in an unweighted graph".  I'm not sure which algorithm that refers to (I don't happen to have that algorithm memorized).

Comment: @D.W. Hi D.W., that algorithm is defined, explained and proved between step 2 and step 3 for more clarity, I'm sorry that you didn't understand that. So in that case,  please look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover , in the section of "Approximate evaluation".

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Hi Yuval, thanks for commenting, as I stated above, my struggle is: will there always exist a graph of size n (when n is even) that will always maintain the condition that its vertex cover set (when using the 2-approx algorithm of VC on that particular graph) will be exactly twice the minimum vertex cover of that graph. And I tried to show more specifically, that this graph will also be bipartite for any given even n. so it's 2-approx vertex cover set output will also always be equal to -exactly- twice the minimum vertex cover.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Yes, there always is such a graph, and this is precisely what the question is asking you to prove. Indeed, there is always a bipartite example. But you're not constructing any particular graph in your proof attempt, so I doubt that you are able to show it. Instead, most of your proof seems to just reprove the fact that your algorithm gives a 2-approximation. We already know that. Now we want an example showing that the analysis is tight – that there are some cases in which the approximation ratio is indeed 2.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Well, isn't it just enough to say that there always exists a graph, and that graph is actually could always be a bipartite type of graph? Should I really show an example? If yes, how would I do it? Maybe with induction? Like for example, showing for n = 2 is easy, then assuming for n it's correct, but the struggle will be I guess to show for n + 2 ?

Comment: You can't say that there always exists a graph without explaining *why* such a graph should always exist. Perhaps the algorithm is actually a 1.5-approximation, but all we could prove is that it is a 2-approximation? How can we know? Only by giving explicit examples (or proving that ones exist) in which the algorithm actually gives a solution which is twice the optimum (or, more generally, $2-\epsilon$ times the optimum, for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$). Now that you know what you have to do, I suggest spending a few more hours on the question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Well, if I use one more Lemma and thus prove that ;the size of vertex cover produced by the algorithm will not be larger than twice of the optimum solution', can I conclude from here that if n is even, and the sets of the the bipartite graph will also be even (n/2 = even), then when running the algorithm, it will yield exactly twice the number of minimum vertex cover?

Comment: We already know that the size of the vertex cover produced by the algorithm is at most twice the optimum. You can't conclude from that there there is a graph for which the factor 2 is tight. If I prove $a \leq b$, I cannot conclude $a = b$, no matter how many times I reiterate the proof of $a \leq b$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I see, you're right, so actually I thought a little bit about a graph which is bipartite, I'll divide the graph into two disjoint sets, n/2 in each set, and let's make it visually simple in our imagination, the two sets are parallel, so every node is in the same x-axis value (but different y values), for example x=1 in first set, and x=1 in the second set, their y-values differ. we'll draw a line between every two vertices that are on same x-axis. now because of the algorithm, it will always take all the vertices in the graph which are exactly n, and Minimum-VC will be always n/2.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus addition to my explanation: It'll always take all the nodes in the graph because it must go on all the edges in the graph. and thus it'll gather all the nodes in the graph. the minimum vertex cover set will also ALWAYS be n/2 because we'll have to take either u or v in (u,v), and then we'll remove the edge, and continue like that.. so exactly half of number of vertiecs.

Comment: Right, this graph is known as a *matching*.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus so I can conclude that this and all the details I mentioned in my "steps" prove the question? :)

Comment: You don’t need any of the steps.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you very much for your time and effort! Highly appreciated as always.